# Progress bar for Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

I have created a Java swing application for downloading file using a Java servlet.

The client machine has a GUI which provides a list of file to download.

How do I set a progress bar to monitor the file download?

This is the code for client machine:

```
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String value = comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        HttpGet post = new HttpGet(
            "http://localhost:8080/may16/FileDownloadServletNormal?value="
            + value + "&type=normal");
        try {
            LocalTime time1 = new LocalTime();

            // executing the POST request
            HttpResponse rsp = client.execute(post);
            // reading response data
            HttpEntity entity = rsp.getEntity();

            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("D://temp//downloaded//" + value));

            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);

            /*try {
             Thread.sleep(25000);
             } 
             catch (InterruptedException e) {
             //TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
             }*/

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            LocalTime time2 = new LocalTime();
            Seconds sec = Seconds.secondsBetween(time1, time2);
            System.out.println("Time Taken:" + sec.getSeconds() + "secs");
            //normalDownloadTime.setText("Normal download time:"+sec.getSeconds());
            normalDownloadTime.setText("Normal download time:"
                + sec.getSeconds() + "secs");
            // String response = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
            //  System.out.println(response);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) & [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html).